# moment.js coverts date to different format

Tags: javascript, momentjs

So i am trying to convert a `mm/dd/yyyy` format, but i am getting this as output `00/Tu/yyyy`, the date object itself works fine if i print it on console.

```
$('#startDate').on('change', function () {
        var start_date = $("#startDate").val();

        // var datePart = start_date.split(/[^0-9]+/);
        var today = moment(new Date(start_date)).format("mm/dd/yyyy");
        console.log(today);
        $("#endDate").val(start_date);
    });
```

Comment: have you tried "MM/DD/YYYY"

Comment: or moment().format('L'); (from https://momentjs.com/)

Comment: @GonzaloLorieto: your 1st comment worked , and whats the difference b/w the 2?

Comment: Because format structures need to be case-sensitve. For example "mm" means minutes not month, so month must be capital M.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moment format tokens are **case sensitive** so you have to use `MM/DD/YYYY` instead of `mm/dd/yyyy`.

Uppercase `MM` stands for month (01 02 ... 11 12), while lowercase `mm` stands for minutes (00 01 ... 58 59); uppercase `DD` stands for day of the month (01 02 ... 30 31), while lowercase `dd` stands for day of the week (Su Mo ... Fr Sa). There is no lowercase `yyyy` token but you have to use uppercase `YYYY` for year.

See moment [`format()`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) docs for further reference.

You are getting `00/Tu/yyyy` because your input represent a *moment* with 0 minutes of a Tuesday.

Moreover note that you do not need to pass a JS Date object to moment (`new Date(start_date)`), but you can use moment [parsing functions](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/).

Answer (score 1):

Check momentJS docs for all the formatting options: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/

'L' or 'MM/DD/YYYY' should work fine.